# installation ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside windows 7

Tags: system-installation

After reading the instructions guide I need some support .

A-in step 3 ,ALLOCTE DRIVE SPACE .enclosed link 
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop 
I can not see the screen which indicate how to choose installation alongside 
  window 7 .do I choose the option: 
  -**something eles** ,*or*

-**erase disk and install ububtu** ?Is this option will not erase my  windows 
     system operation ?

B- In the installation procedure .Could I to  choose the zise of the 
   partation ?or I have to make it before the ubuntu  installation .

C- After the installation could I choose select to operate in ubuntu or windows 
   with seperate icons or I have to select it in another way?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

- **erase disk and install ububtu**: It would remove all existing partitions and start again.
- **something else**: you have some options to edit in your disk.

A - I think the best case in here you should choose **something else** to ensure your options on saving your current data from another disk.

B - In something else option, you can choose your size of partition.

C - After installing Ubuntu, there is shown one boot menu for you to choose your installed operating system

Good luck!